# Html.DisplayNameFor DataType.Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, displayfor

I have a simple view model

```
public string LinkName { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Url")]
[DataType(DataType.Url)]
public string Link
{
  get
  {
     return string.Format(/*some link building logic*/);
  }
}
```

But when I try to display it in view with

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Link)
```

I'm getting whole Url displayed and I'd like to just display LinkName i.e something like this

```
<a href="http://...">http://...</a>
```

but I'd like to have it like this:

```
<a href="http://...">LinkName</a>
```

Comment: Do you mean `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LinkName)`? What is the value of `Link` and `LinkName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for MVC to pull in a value from another property when you use `DisplayFor` so you have 2 options. First you can build it manually:

```
<a href="@Model.Url">@Model.LinkName</a>
```

The next option would be to make your own class and custom display template. For example:

```
public class NamedUrl
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Your new model:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public NamedUrl MyUrl { get; set; }
}
```

The display template (put it in `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/NamedUrl.cshtml`):

```
@model YourAssembly.NamedUrl
<a href="@Model.Url">@Model.LinkName</a>
```

And now in your view you can use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyUrl)
```

Comment: And what about @html.ActionLinks? wont this be even better option?

Comment: ActionLink implies you have the name of an action and not a full url to play with.